# Files show up under unstaged even after commit on Sourcetree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

So I'm having some confusion in understanding why I have files showing up as unstaged even though I just made a commit and pushed. I would provide a picture but it wouldn't explain the problem.

Put simply, I believe that my partner correctly staged all of the files before committing the first time(I hope). But now I am seeing (on Sourcetree) a huge list of "Unstaged files" even after staging all the files and committing. I have tried running `git add -A` to add all the files and committing, but the files still appear as unstaged in Sourcetree. Whenever running `git ls-files` I believe I am seeing the files that exist in the unstaged section of Sourcetree but am not totally sure. What's going on here?

Comment: Conflict between project .gitignore and your user .gitignore?